# iAd ad closure results in new instance of the application's view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, iad

I've created a SpriteKit game where i create a banner ad in the main view controller and then hide and unhide the banner as required using NSNotification Center.  That all works great from any SKScene in the game.

But if i click on the ad, and then eventually close it, instead of going back to the original SKScene a new view controller instance is created and i appear back at the first scene...like the whole application just rebooted.

In the view controller the banner ad is set up as follows:

```
    - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

{
        [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

```
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

    _banner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(_banner.frame, 0, 0)];
    _banner.delegate = self;
    _banner.hidden = TRUE;
    [self.view addSubview:_banner];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.originalContentView;

    MainMenu* scene = [MainMenu sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [skView presentScene:scene];
```

Here's the delegate methods:

```
    - (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

    bannerAdIsLoaded = TRUE;

    NSLog(@"Banner ad is loaded");
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

    bannerAdIsLoaded = FALSE;

    NSLog(@"Failed to receive banner ad");
}

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner   willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave {
    NSLog(@"Starting banner ad action");

    return YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"Banner ad Did Finish");

}


-(void)bannerViewWillLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"Loading a banner ad...");
}
```

When the ad is dismissed, how can i make it return to the last SKScene, where the ad was launched, and not relaunch the the application?

Comment: iAd is going away on June 30, FYI--> http://9to5mac.com/2016/01/15/apple-will-discontinue-iad-app-network-for-developers-on-june-30th/

Comment: switching to admob is really easy.  But to answer the question, closing the ad should automatically take you back to the scene,  since you do not post your code when a banner is finished, I can't tell you why you are spawning a new instance

Comment: As far as I understand iAd closing only affects developers publishing ads to the iAd App network. Developers just integrating ads should not be affected because iAd itself is not  shutting down